# Using 前 and 後 with Time versus Duration

Tags: translation, readings, time

I have the following 2 sentences to translate for class.

Sentence 1:

> 頭痛がするので、
>   **四時前**に
>   帰らせていただけますか。

Sentence 2:

> **四日後**のしけんは、
>   むずかしいかわからないので、
>   自信が持てなくて、
>       心配だ。

I think these mean the following.

Sentence 1

> I have a headache so 
>   before 4 o'clock 
>   can I go home? (can I receive your action of letting me return home)

Sentence 2

> As for the ... test, 
>   I didn't know whether it would be difficult so 
>   I could not have confidence and 
>   I was worried.

I have the following questions.

1. Is my translation of sentence 1 correct? Specifically the "before 4 o'clock" part.
2. Would the 四時前 be said as よじまえ?
3. Is my translation of sentence 2 correct (what I have). And how is the missing part translated? (test after the 4th day, 4th, etc)
4. How would the 四日後 be said? よっかご? よっかあと?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I believe there's nothing wrong with your translation for the first sentence.
2. Yes.
3. As for the test (I'm having) in/after four days, I **don't** know whether or not it will be difficult, so I **don't** have confidence (I am not confident/ I have no confidence), and I **am** worried.
4. よっかご

The translations for both sentences could of-course be better phrased to sound more natural in English but may be you were asked to do a more literal translation?